# How to Add Custom Time Format?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, error-handling

I am making a NetcafeProgram in C# and I want to get the current DateTime. I want my output like this (hr.mins)"0.25". I have the current DateTime but I want to show it like this (hr.mins)"0.25" in the labelTime_1 but it is not working. This is the command which I used

```
starttime_1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
```

and I changed it to

```
starttime_1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("h.mm");
```

and then I wanted to get the duration like this

```
TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(endtime_1).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(starttime_1));
```

but it gives me errors.

Here is a Screenshot of My Formv:

[image]

I want the time to get posted On that Time Elapsed Label but it doesn't work. Here is the coding of BtnStop1

```
private void btnStop_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string duration = Convert.ToInt32(((starttime_1) - (endtime_1)));
    gbx_1.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
    btnStop_1.Enabled = false;
    //endtime_1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
    //TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(endtime_1).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(starttime_1));
    endtime_1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("h.mm tt");
    TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(endtime_1).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(starttime_1));
    lblTime_1.Text = Convert.ToString(duration);
    string var = "Cabin One is Free";
    btnStart_1.Enabled = true;
    HP_1.Enabled = true;
    CR_1.Enabled = true;
    reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    reader.SpeakAsync(var);
}
```

Coding of BtnStart

```
private void btnStart_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gbx_1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    btnStart_1.Enabled = false;
    //starttime_1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
    starttime_1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("h.mm tt");
    lblTime_1.Text = "CountingTime";
    string var = "Cabin One is Occupied";
    reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    reader.SpeakAsync(var);
    HP_1.Enabled = false;
    CR_1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Here Are My Variables

```
public string starttime_1;
public string starttime_2;
public string starttime_3;
public string starttime_4;
public string starttime_5;
public string starttime_6;
public string endtime_1;
public string endtime_2;
public string endtime_3;
public string endtime_4;
public string endtime_5;
public string endtime_6;
```

Comment: Why are you formatting all these strings, just to then parse them again? Don't do that... and for timing, you'd be better off just keeping hold of a `Stopwatch` that you could ask for the elapsed time. (I'd also strongly recommend against using public variables, and against using underscores in variable names, and against using multiple names that vary only by number...)

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest changing your variable types to `DateTime?`. It is better to store data in its native type and then do the convert to string on display. This way, when you want the duration, you are not parsing back to `DateTime`. You can handle any rounding you want on the base data.

So, your conversion to `string` should be at the highest level of you stack. It will keep your code cleaner and make it easier to refactor the logic away from the UI later if appropriate.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to send it to the database but it was not working, so i wanted it to come out in crystal reports so now i have a problem again that i want to send my variables in my database so its notworking im trying ot find a solution

Comment: I would use the same approach for the db. Keep the fields as DateTime. Then, for your reports handle the formatting in the stored procedures (or perhaps views). SQL's date formatting is great.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure I understand all this parsing but if you're just trying to record start and stop times and output a timespan I would do as Jon Skeet recommend with the stopwatch.  Something along these lines looks like what you're going for but a bit cleaner.

```
// Build stopwatch and lists
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
List<string> startTimes = new List<string>();
List<string> endTimes = new List<string>();

private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Start stopwatch and record start time
    sw.Start();
    startTimes.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("h.mm"));
}

private void stopBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Stop stopwatch
    sw.Stop();

    // Record stop time and reset stopwatch
    endTimes.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("h.mm"));
    sw.Reset();

    // Output timespan
    outputLbl.Text = sw.Elapsed.ToString();
}
```